# Why @Autowired didn't work in static method

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I found many solutions to this issue, and choose the below one.

But it still gets `NullpointerException`, what's wrong?

**A Class**

```
@Component
public class A {

    private static Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        A.foo = foo;
    }

    public static someFunction() {
        foo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**B Class**

```
@Service
public class B {

    public void someFunction() {
        A.someFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Autowired is about instantiated objects, you don't instantiate said object. Why would you even want this?

Comment: Did you make Foo a bean, component or service? Share code related to Foo please.

Comment: Foo is a existed service, I want to use some method of it

Comment: What is your scenario, that you need static method? Usually there is just one been in the spring context. Autowiring a bean in a class will be the same autowired bean in another class. Except you define the been to be prototype.

Comment: Hey guys, I resolved this problem finally.
This code has no problem, the problem is spring component-scan doesn't scan the folder of A class.
After I edited the spring config, it's all good now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot auto-wire static properties in Spring, Static fields are instantiated during class load as they are the properties of the class while auto wired attributes work after spring initializes the beans. 
Although you may use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`in Spring to achieve what you wanted.
some example would be in XML as below

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="foo.bar.Class.setTheProperty"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="theProperty"/>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Edit :- without XML
inside your `@Configuration` class 
do

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod("MyClass.staticMethod");

    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

let me know in case you need more help.

Comment: Is there an option without xml?

Comment: @user7294900 I have updated the answer accept it also if you think it works for you.

Comment: I have resolved this problem, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Roil.Li would you accept the answer also that would be great.